# How can I print the value of an object inside html document?

Tags: html, angularjs

I have an angularJS function that takes a value from checkbox set - which check box was checked (true or false) and stores this info in an object. Then it creates a variable, that stores value of the first element of the object. How can I print this value inside html document? I tried this:

```js
// app.js

var formApp = angular.module('formApp', [])

    .controller('formController', function($scope) {
  
        // we will store our form data in this object
        $scope.formData = {};

var answer = formData[Object.keys(formData)[0]];
       
    });
```

```html
<-- index.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <!-- CSS -->
    <!-- load up bootstrap and add some spacing -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <style>
        body         { padding-top:50px; }
        form         { margin-bottom:50px; }
    </style>

    <!-- JS -->
    <!-- load up angular and our custom script -->
    <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.13/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<!-- apply our angular app and controller -->
<body ng-app="formApp" ng-controller="formController">
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1">

    <h2>Angular Checkboxes </h2>

  
...

    <!-- MULTIPLE CHECKBOXES -->
    <label>Favorite Colors</label>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="checkbox-inline">
            <input type="checkbox" name="favoriteColors" ng-model="formData.favoriteColors.red"> Red
        </label><br>
        <label class="checkbox-inline">
            <input type="checkbox" name="favoriteColors" ng-model="formData.favoriteColors.blue"> Blue
        </label> <br>
        <label class="checkbox-inline">
            <input type="checkbox" name="favoriteColors" ng-model="formData.favoriteColors.green"> Green
        </label>
    </div>

...
    
    <!-- SHOW OFF OUR FORMDATA OBJECT -->
    <h2>Sample Form Object</h2>
    <pre>
        [[answer]]
    </pre>
    
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @nareshvadlakonda i tried, no effect. It works with the object (formData), but not with the variable (answer).

Comment: if you print any variables value in html you need do it using expression evalutor operator or ng-bind

Comment: can u provide a plunker

Comment: @nareshvadlakonda I allreay have liveweave version, is it ok? http://liveweave.com/XnDpb8

Answer (score 1):

You can directly do the binding as:

```
<pre>{{formData.favoriteColors.red}}</pre>
```

using: `Object.keys(formData)` will not guarantee you will be getting the first value. The sorting will be based on the hash key.

Comment: Actually I will need to write if-else conditions for different values of the object elements, so I trued to understand how to get value of the first element, to be able to get also values of the other elements later. So any methods are very interesting to me, thank you!

Comment: change your pre tag to following:
<pre>
<p ng-show="formData.favoriteColors.red">Red</p>
<p ng-show="formData.favoriteColors.blue">Blue</p>
<p ng-show="formData.favoriteColors.green">Green</p>
    </pre>
and
remover the 'answer' variable from your controller and html

Answer (score 0):

the variable answer needs to be declared inside your scope, so your controller would look like this :

```
var formApp = angular.module('formApp', [])

    .controller('formController', function($scope) {

        // we will store our form data in this object
        $scope.formData = {};
        $scope.answer = formData[Object.keys(formData)[0]];

    });
```

then in your html you can use

```
{{answer}}
```

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't work, maybe a made some mistake, trying to figure it out now.